# How can I use a file from the local disk in Pulumi?

Tags: typescript, pulumi

I am trying to use a long policy document for AWS in Pulumi that sits on disk.

```
const policyDocument = new pulumi.asset.FileAsset("./policy.json");
```

However, when I try to use the variable later like this:

```
export const jobPolicy = new aws.iam.Policy(`${ jobName }-policy`, {
  path: `/${ stage }`,
  description: `Policy for ETL job ${ jobName }`,
  policy: JSON.stringify(policyDocument)
});
```

I get the following:

```
 + policy     : "{\"__pulumiAsset\":true,\"path\":{}}"
```

Is there a way to somehow use a JSON file in Pulumi + TypeScript?

I also tried:

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
const policyDocument  = fs.readFileSync('policy.json', 'utf8');
```

The result is:

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'policy.json' 
> at Object.openSync (node:fs:585:3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `pulumi.asset.FileAsset` creates new resources, with inputs and outputs. It's generally used to create lambda functions.

The `policy` parameter takes a standard TypeScript string, so you were on the right lines using `fs.readFileSync`, but I think you forgot to add the path to the `json` file. You could probably do:

```
const policyDocument  = fs.readFileSync('./policy.json','utf8');
```

Notice the `./` there. However, a safer way is to resolve the directory using `path`. Try something like this

```
import * as pulumi from "@pulumi/pulumi";
import * as aws from "@pulumi/aws";
import * as fs from 'fs';
const path = require('path');

const policyDocument = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'policy.json'), 'utf8');

const jobPolicy = new aws.iam.Policy('file-policy', {
    policy: policyDocument
});
```

Comment: Writing policies for AWS in Javascript/Typescript becomes much simpler with this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@thinkinglabs/aws-iam-policy

Comment: Use `import * as path from 'path';` instead of `require` to keep code consistent